# Selected variation color price doesn't showing on mouse click

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, product-variations

On the following web page:

http://steel-classics.com/de/produkt/le-corbusier-2-sitzer-sofa-lc3/

I have the following problem:

When I click for example Verona or Liguria (Materials) and then choose any Leather color, the price for chosen variation doesn't appear.

The following code is used for displaying variation price, but it doesn't appear.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ 
        data.variation.variation_description }}}
    </div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ 
        data.variation.price_html }}}
    </div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ 
        data.variation.availability_html }}}
    </div>
</script>
```

I've also tried to change display property from `none;` to `block!important!;` in `ivpa-hidden-price` class.

Then it is showing the price range again, as above on the page, but not the actual selected variation price.

Does anyone have a possible solution how to make variation price appear on mouse click on the selected variation because this should be working by default in outstock theme, and I don't know what is blocking it from working.

Thanks in advance to everyone who atleast invested time to read this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these are configured as variable products in woocommerce.
In the woocommerce product options inside the dashboard, have you actually modified the "Regular Price" for each variation (by clicking expand on the variation under the variations tab)?

Comment: yes, thats all already setup. Each leather type has different price, Liguria has it price and Verona its own price. Thats not an issue

Comment: In the console there is a js script missing (giving 404). Maybe that one's responbile for the functionality you're after? The script missing is named owl.carousel.js in themes/outstock/owl-carousel 

http://steel-classics.com/wp-content/themes/outstock/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js?ver=4.9.8

Comment: that JS file has nothing to do with variation colors

Comment: @DigitalWhirlLLC, your [`custom.js`](http://steel-classics.com/wp-content/themes/outstock/js/custom.js?ver=1530696685) file is calling `jQuery.fn.owlCarousel()`, but since the carousel script is *not* loaded - which means `jQuery.fn.owlCarousel` is `undefined`, the console throws an error which I believe prevented the variation script from being executed properly. So fix the carousel script's path and see if that fixes the variation price visibility issue.

Comment: ok, seems like that a partial solution, the price now appears, but disappear when I select second variation. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: @DigitalWhirlLLC Maybe a CSS issue, but I see that you've fixed it? And you should also fix this: In the same `custom.js` file, in the `jQuery.ajaxComplete()` call, `xhr` is `undefined` and hence `xhr.abort();` should be `request.abort();`.